# Not able to deploy Openshift on AWS using QuickStart Guide

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, amazon-cloudformation, openshift-origin, openshift-online-3

Thanks for your support.

I am trying to deploy the Open-shift on aws using AWS Quickstart guide, as mentioned [here](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-redhat-openshift/doc/red-hat-openshift-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf).

My deployment is gets Rollback as it is unable to deploy below resources:

1. OpenShiftNodeASG,
2. AnsibleConfigServer,
3. OpenShiftEtcdASG,
4. OpenShiftMasterASG

Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image: Failed to deploy resource]

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide events of that failing nested CF stack? It is clear what is failing but not why. Providing such events could help.